# TypeScript: How to use generated Union Type correctly in a loop?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I have the following type:

```
type Updater<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    key: K;
    update: (value: string) => T[K];
  };
}[keyof T]
```

Here my intention is to have some generic updaters for any type that takes an input and update each individual property with an update function, which has type enforced so the output matches with the type of the property. This purpose is served:

```
type TestType = {
  fieldA: string;
  fieldB: number;
}

type TestTypeUpdater = Updater<TestType>[];

const testTypeUpdater: TestTypeUpdater = [
  {
    key: "fieldA", // enforced to be one of "fieldA" or "fieldB"
    update: s => s + "(updated)" // enforced to output the type of "fieldA"
  },{
    key: "fieldB",
    update: s => s.length      // enforced to output the type of "fieldB"
  }
];
```

However, when I try to use it, it is not as I expected. What I wanted to do is:

```
const testType: TestType = {
  fieldA: "",
  fieldB: 0
}

function test(input: string) {
  for (const u of testTypeUpdater) {
    testType[u.key] = u.update(input);
  }
}

test("input");
```

I was expecting it is as simple as the above, but TypeScript is complaining under `testType[u.key]`:

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
```

It seems the fact that the return type of `update` is `T[K]` is lost but becomes a union of `string | number`. What I had to do to stop that was:

```
function testOK(input: string) {
  for (const u of testTypeUpdater) {
    if (u.key === "fieldA") {
      testType[u.key] = u.update(input);
    } else if (u.key === "fieldB") {
      testType[u.key] = u.update(input);
    }
  }
}

testOK("input");
```

The fact that I need to repeat again each property name in the type in the loop defeats the whole purpose to generate the union type with `keyof`.

How do you make the version of the loop without needing to check for the property name works?

---

Added:
What if the `Updater` is a dictionary type, e.g.:

```
type Updater<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    update: (value: string) => T[K];
  };
}

type TestType = {
  fieldA: string;
  fieldB: number;
}

type TestTypeUpdater = Updater<TestType>;

const testTypeUpdater: TestTypeUpdater = {
  fieldA: { // enforced to be one of "fieldA" or "fieldB"
    update: s => s + "(updated)" // enforced to output the type of "fieldA"
  },
  fieldB: {
    update: s => s.length      // enforced to output the type of "fieldB"
  }
};

const testType: TestType = {
  fieldA: "",
  fieldB: 0
}

function test(input: string) {
  Object.keys(testTypeUpdater).forEach(k => {
    testType[k] = testTypeUpdater[k].update(input);
  });
}

test("input");
```

Comment: This is the subject of [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), which is addressed by [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). If I apply the fix suggested there it looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLlk2m).  Does that address your question?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Oh great! I got your attention. Thanks @jcalz for chasing after this issue for 4 some years.  I don't mind additional typing as long as I don't need to repeat the property names or use casting. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've run into an issue I call "correlated union types", as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  Many cases of this have been addressed by [indexed access inference improvements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#indexed-access-inference-improvements) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), although it tends to require some refactoring.

---

The problem with

```
function test(input: string) {
  for (const u of testTypeUpdater) {
    testType[u.key] = u.update(input);
  }
}
```

is that the compiler cannot track the *correlation* between the type of `u.key` and the type of `u.update(input)`. This is what it sees:

```
const uKey = u.key; // "fieldA" | "fieldB"
const uUpdated = u.update(input) // string | number
testType[uKey] = uUpdated; // error!
```

Note how each of `uKey` and `uUpdated` are of [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  These types aren't *wrong*; it's true that `uKey` could be either of those two string literals, and that `uUpdated` could be either a `string` or a `number`. But it's treating these as *independent* or *uncorrelated* types.  As far as the compiler can see from these types, `uKey` might be `"fieldA"` while `uUpdated` might be `number`.  And so the assignment fails.

This inability to track union correlations is the subject of microsoft/TypeScript#30581.  You can work around it either by writing redundant code, as you've shown... or by using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the error:

```
testType[uKey] = uUpdated as never; // fixed I guess?
```

---

But... you can also refactor using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  The basic idea is to use a *distributive object type* as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109.  Here's what we can do to `Updater<T>`:

```
type Updater<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = { [P in K]: {
    key: P;
    update: (value: string) => T[P];
}; }[K]
```

So the type `Updater<T>` is the same as before, but you can narrow it to just one key `K` of `T` by specifying it as `Updater<T, K>`.  For example:

```
type TestTypeUpdaterEither = Updater<TestType>;
/* type TestTypeUpdaterEither = {
    key: "fieldA";
    update: (value: string) => string;
} | {
    key: "fieldB";
    update: (value: string) => number;
} */

type TestTypeUpdaterFieldA = Updater<TestType, "fieldA">
/* type TestTypeUpdaterFieldA = {
    key: "fieldA";
    update: (value: string) => string;
} */
```

And now, we change your `for..of` loop to a [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) call, so we can pass in a callback which is generic in `K`, some particular key of `TestType`.  The compiler allows assignments of `TestType[K]` to the generic `K` property of a `TestType` value.  (This is actually unsafe too, if `K` is specified with a union, but the compiler permits this and we need to use it in order to proceed.  And we won't actually be doing anything unsafe with it.)

It looks like this:

```
testTypeUpdater.forEach(<K extends keyof TestType>(u: Updater<TestType, K>) => {
    const uKey = u.key; // K
    const uUpdated = u.update(input) // TestType[K]
    testType[uKey] = uUpdated; // okay
}
```

It works!  Oh, and I guess we don't need to break those apart into individual variables:

```
testTypeUpdater.forEach(<K extends keyof TestType>(u: Updater<TestType, K>) => {
    testType[u.key] = u.update(input); // okay
})
```

Still works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqmAmBDYEBOAeAKgGigaSggA8UA7eAZygGsIQB7AMykygF4a6mWA+dqAN5QA2gAUoAS1L4AugC5BAKCgrOIBaIDcy1QFcEyCAoAUAN0QAbXUagVgqKQHMAlOz6YxM7QF9NUb8J4MoohoJAsEHaY4NAcAjoqjBIQFvAAggp2DqSO2qpQSSnwAEIKpLoAtgBGaD4himHQmJHA0ZBwSCioAKISwAAWaPwdhhjNUTE82gD0AFRQjRET7QZdvQNDcQlqCgBEhalpu3l6qzZmltaZ9k6ubHxZTj5QAD5K+bTqUPvJqcXH230nXO5isNkeOTufHK1Vqim8UFm01CMSWrRiIy6ADFfulhmcxi02hBcD8ikceIo5gtUeN0StgagceT+PEPnQ9gd0gD8kDDCZQVdbDdIW5hdlcvDEciGrSiRiCfjGVh5ZAeMIvCEAMb0Uh2BaqiCYtAKOnE42ofjCbZs-KqT6c3FHXDTaaEUiMeioLUQeALehQGpQXXQbhkw67YOW8MlXbbXlnTJiqgAam+xj5KHgzkjrvdnu9vv9wd0wDApYWgxp4TDXKO228uFtdp23y5-2w8dOwKT91sADoLBAcgMW3nhwWfX7gAH6KXy8BK9BFrXcf8G4pNdrdfqUMsbGbUVt8nW9rtOye1woAAzwkKMXSkLXACS6wOIeB04xSBfXCWuZsCi9KBjB1PVF10YNmD3ekjQJACuxUMD9V0PA6H4XR+0+Pw8xjI5XjbNc4xbJCdwg40-Q4TDMwgb9SAXVw8whRwCJhGpUEQg192EVC6BkDCKJwt00FQL0AEJOJg4keLQkB+KoiioEQKhSAgUxaigPMkiIIsAEkoEcawKAoAB+DdvHvR9n1faQYLo39xVud5VCkhVGX7AtukQLV+mMdACGIMhKDUbhDzVDMFAtFV91wPAeChZyW1cyAeKwviMP7Gj7NLZwhODahEBATjkIg2SMuwzS3TwYqyKgXRFKozKzmy4BGLdMKIECYISK42CZPShSzngPL6AKor8m8Zw7waFpjF2H9S12XKQiAA)

Comment: Absolutely fantastic answer! Explained the why first, then provided the steps leading to a solution, also supplemented with references! The role model of SO answer! I small question I have, can I still use for...of loop instead of forEach loop? And what if my `Updater` is a dictionary type (i.e. remove the [K] at the end and `TestTypeUpdater` is a dictionary instead of an array), is there a solution for an `Object.keys/values/entries` loop on this new updater? Thank you

Comment: If you use `for..of` then you will have to call some generic function in each loop like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nr512w), which is pretty much like `forEach()`.  If you have a dictionary then it's maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9EkJN) but I don't see what you mean about removing the `[K]`.

Comment: Cool. thanks! And by removing the `[K]`, I gave an example in my updated question.