# Discrimination of a union of types using the type of a correlated argument variable

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I have the following types and an enum:

```
enum TableNames {
  clients = "clients",
  products = "products"
}

interface IClient {
  client: string;
  location: string;
  type: string;
}
interface IProduct {
  product: string;
  family: string;
  subfamily: string;
}

type TSelector<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K][];
};

type TClientSelector = TSelector<IClient>;
type TProductSelector = TSelector<IProduct>;
```

These two classes initialize an object based on `TClientSelector` and `TProductSelector`.

```
export class BaseClientSelector implements TClientSelector {
  client: string[] = [];
  type: string[] = [];
  location: string[] = [];
}

export class BaseProductSelector implements TProductSelector {
  product: string[] = [];
  family: string[] = [];
  subfamily: string[] = [];
}
```

Factory function that uses variable `name` to dispatch an object with type `TClientSelector` or `TProductSelector`.

```
const getEmptySelectorObject = (name: TableNames): TClientSelector | TProductSelector => {
  if (name === TableNames.clients) {
    return new BaseClientSelector();
  } else {
    return new BaseProductSelector();
  }
};
```

And here lies the problem. Consider the following function:

```
export const getSelectorData = (
  arrayOfObj: (IClient | IProduct)[],
  name: TableNames
): TClientSelector | TProductSelector => {
  const selectorData: TClientSelector | TProductSelector = getEmptySelectorObject(name);

  for (const col in selectorData) {
    selectorData[col] = Array.from(
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TS7053
      new Set(arrayOfObj.map((obj: IClient | IProduct) => obj[col]))
//                                                        ^^^^^^^^ TS7053
    ).sort((a, b) => String(a).localeCompare(String(b)));
  }

  return selectorData;
};
```

I know that if `name` has type `TableNames.clients`, then `selectorData` has to be of type `TClientSelector`. But, since TypeScript cannot know which type will `selectorData` have because I do not know how to express this relationship to it then, when iterating over the keys of `selectorData`, it defaults to assigning `col` to type `string`. This prompts the compiler to tell me that `TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'TSelector<IClient> | TSelector<IProduct>'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'TSelector<IClient> | TSelector<IProduct>'`.

Something similar happens inside the map where `obj` can be either `IClient` or `IProduct` so `col` cannot be used to index it.

Solutions I have tried that do not convince me:

- Code repetition with a type guard.
- Adding explicit `any`s.
- Function overloading (one for `TClientSelector` and another for `TProductSelector`.

I am fairly certain that this can be solved using generics but I cannot wrap my head around them.

I found this answer by jcalz https://stackoverflow.com/a/72294288 that  uses a *distributive object type* and something tells me this could be the answer but I cannot adapt that solution to my problem.

Comment: It can indeed be solved with generics and a distributive object type as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NBVPDN), if you think it's worth it.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes! It does fully address the question, but I would be lying if I said I understand half of what is going on in that playground. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now even the call side of `getSelectorData()` is a problem, since the correlation between the two arguments is not represented.  Your call signature looks like:

```
declare const getSelectorData: (
  arrayOfObj: (IClient | IProduct)[], name: TableNames
) => TClientSelector | TProductSelector;
```

And so it allows this:

```
getSelectorData([{ client: "a", location: "b", type: "c" }],
  TableNames.products
) // no error, but there should be.
```

You could enforce that correlation with a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) of [rest parameter tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types):

```
declare const getSelectorData: (
  ...[arrayOfObj, name]:
    [IClient[], TableNames.clients] |
    [IProduct[], TableNames.products]
) => TClientSelector | TProductSelector;

getSelectorData(
  [{ client: "a", location: "b", type: "c" }], // error!
  TableNames.products
);
getSelectorData(
  [{ client: "a", location: "b", type: "c" }], // okay
  TableNames.clients
)
```

But this only helps from the caller's side.

---

The implementation still has errors, and that's because TypeScript doesn't support "correlated [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)" types very well, where a single block of code would need to be analyzed once for each possible narrowing of some union-typed expression, as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

In your function implementation, you'd want the compiler to notice that things are fine if the function arguments are of type `[IClient[], TableNames.clients]` and they're also fine if they are of type `[IProduct[], TableNames.products]`, so they are fine overall.  But TypeScript doesn't do any sort of "distributive" [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) (not even on an "opt-in" basis as suggested in [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051)). What happens instead is that the compiler treats each union-typed value as independent, and so even if the call signature has prevented from passing in `[IClient[], TableNames.products]`, the compiler doesn't realize that in the implementation.  And so it complains.

---

The official recommended way to fix things like this is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). The idea is to switch away from unions and towards [generics]https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) that are [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the keys of some base interface.  And then you'd have to rewrite all your types and operations in terms of that base interface, [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that interface, and generic [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into them.

But doing so is often a significant refactoring and can be hard to follow.  If you want expedience, you should just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or use [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) after double checking that your implementation is good.  The cure might be worse than the disease.

You be the judge:

---

In your case I'd refactor as follows.  Here's the basic interface representing the relationship you want to abstract over:

```
interface TableMap {
  [TableNames.clients]: IClient,
  [TableNames.products]: IProduct
}
```

Now you can rewrite `TSelector` as generic over the *key* of `TableMap`, like this:

```
type ArrayProps<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K][] }
type TSelectorMap<K extends TableNames> = { [P in K]: ArrayProps<TableMap[P]> }
type TSelector<K extends TableNames> = TSelectorMap<K>[K]
```

The utility type `ArrayProps<T>` just makes it easy to represent what you want `TSelector<K>` to be.  Note that `TSelector<K>` is indexing into a mapped type with all its keys, which makes it a *distributive object type* as coined in ms/TS#47109.  I named `TSelectorMap<K>` to be just the mapped type part, since it will be useful later.

Your `TClientSelector` and `TProductSelector` types can be slightly rewritten as:

```
type TClientSelector = TSelector<TableNames.clients>;
type TProductSelector = TSelector<TableNames.products>;
```

and you can verify they are the same as before.

Now, in order for this to work, your `getEmptySelectorObject()` function must be generic the same way. If it returns a union, then we will be stuck.  Since the return type will be `TSelector<K>`, an index into a `TSelectorMap<K>` with a key of type `K`, then the way to convince the compiler this works is to actually make a value of type `TSelectorMap<K>` and index into it.  Here's a `TSelectorMap<TableNames>` (a subtype of `TSelectorMap<K>` for any `K extends TableNames`):

```
const baseSelectors: TSelectorMap<TableNames> = {
  get [TableNames.clients]() { return new BaseClientSelector() },
  get [TableNames.products]() { return new BaseProductSelector() }
}
```

Note that I'm using [getter methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) so that the actual code does not run until someone tries to access the property.  And now the `getEmptySelectorObject()` function implementation just needs to look up `name` in `baseSelectors`:

```
const getEmptySelectorObject = <K extends TableNames>(name: K): TSelector<K> => {
  const _baseSelectors: TSelectorMap<K> = baseSelectors;
  return _baseSelectors[name];
};
```

Well, almost.  The compiler can't "see" that `baseSelectors[name]` is of type `TSelectorMap<K>[K]`.  Instead it only "sees" `TSelectorMap<TableNames>[K]`, and complains. But it does understand that `TSelectorMap<TableNames>` is a subtype of `TSelectorMap<K>`, so we can safely "upcast" by [annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) a new variable of the wider type, and assigning.

And now, finally, `getSelectorData()`:

```
const getSelectorData = <K extends TableNames>(
  arrayOfObj: TableMap[K][],
  name: K
) => {
  const selectorData = getEmptySelectorObject(name);

  for (const col in selectorData) {
    selectorData[col] = Array.from(
      new Set(arrayOfObj.map(obj => obj[col]))
    ).sort((a, b) => String(a).localeCompare(String(b)));
  }
   
  return selectorData;
};
```

It's been made generic, and it works.  There's a little bit of type safety hole remaining; you can still call `getSelectorData()` where `K` is the full `TableNames` union, and the `for` loop doesn't quite check if you're assigning the wrong property to the wrong column (`col` is just `keyof TSelector<K>` more or less, but you would really want a generic `P extends keyof TSelector<K>`)... but that's the first-order refactoring.

So, is it worth it to you?  I couldn't say, but I'd much rather maintain code I personally understood then code someone in Stack Overflow gave me with links to a bunch of GitHub issues.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwdgrgtgBAKgQwEYBsQDkFRAZxgb2BhgGMUBLcAFzwF4YAiMysGhgGiJgAcAnAewAmEEjRj0GfISLbAAvsGBgsubghIgYAeV7kA5gUXFBIMgl6aS-MDiow9IKgGUQaUf14ARBFQQAuGAAKLmJzXgQATy0AMy0kACsAwIBJAGEKahgAHxhkgAUBYVEASgBtAF12GGVsAMRUDBUcLmLxAD54dJZnV1MqD2z4AulRFzd+3gBuI3tHMb6Pb19A0vxSDNYAhgQOGBR+Eh9yay2kXaoI7hAtkgYYOUqQ+GQ0TGwcADopIpoW+UUaqp1JpUggUCgAGLkAAehmMphQ5ks1lssx640WPn8QSeHzxpTCkRicXiVUB5T8T2IpTSGyoFSq9VeTQ+zGoOHK2SpMBpwx+DOeDTeuC+hRkHJa7U6dPm7l4gzgfJksom0y4DnRCy8WOCxGpazZm0YOyq+0OVGOYFO50u10Yt3ulRgAHpnTAQLwBLwAIRPJmNd6ika-YjFabEDUqzHLJ6rdbdLYmvYHI4nRhnKoXK43O4PKqumD8ADWkT9LwDIsNIZgxX+inIrA90WBuS6mUIxCrAVsujAenDyfNlu7VF7-a4WbtPYb44UDaoTZb+TFojhPBXVBHY4Hzag5BQES3M4HOAgSF3+8PMGnfemCnrjd4zY0grQAFkENw16V-cLPlWOQCWluk4alfxZb5xQpXIlVEOtgEnGAAEFPUiYZuBwAAeOAOnoNZSgAaRgBsYCLEAIn4aJ4GguBCPKCp7gQ214CjXgP24TCiJAaEFzAQQ8HA95cIIHk8mIsAYAI6CUPCCJ0Kw-12NKPJyg6BRELgVjOPdHjwH418KxwYTNN6OV2M4to6MUAsNK0nDxBEnkiJIsiKKouAaLoipJnuNUNLbVhWIckyMV4bDyz-Vk6SM6YNNgzU5WCuyIogjcYsUMwcDwAAhBAcBAAKEomYioG4NBsFYATCqCjt42oI8+wY+hvInW0Gr0JqeXKAczVTK1r1HGdOpa+9MpyvKQHioLyFK8r2SGDcaq4SDRHa4buq4C8DzWzlmo24hT3PLBLx2hyRoylE7CQCbWJwOpWPMwTcGE2qNR5J7-2i8pAlaNYLCoCBeAksAQAAdxgXL8uq0yJh++5QLRd6UsDFaaG+36YH+wHgbBiGJqmmGPDhhRRsutEAFFSouViST6BztO43j9I+tpAkBAICOKe7CbCgjcI6WqrBsOwAH1rvy27udC8y+Yc8WQFugcsaBmAxZunmcFKck7zVYAhdRSMeaWBB6a43S+IE5Hnt1GBCSiWIEjqcslKkhkuHZyTgFaWgBa4fW7Hy0LjYcjVKe4amedp0Q2ZUMMZmiAZAn90h+BQcTryNrFfqeQOtWN0orBQXbkNQiIPmiAQoBtvVqlxlwqECO3iQSD4oE-QJ+ASKVO-iAvU-KYpaxr4oPhwDwG8bqokG9jonEGvtG5H3q0FSfhSqRQI57HQJp8Hgd72IZ0ACprwoPQAAsqAPGAoA8TQGBwBBohAO4SKoc+fBgd-NAbQRyAAN3IMIMEpFyLETwA4EGugSAhECFHKgHxXI4ECLnOUxtWh5RLrJTCrlKIGRdqpEeVIE68HJuoc+gRMJiUZnpPAuD3LO0-HRVmhcAh5BnmuGuGcg5Yj7kXByMlIjl0rtXLhtdwb10bqXZu8RW7tx7t3BIfCB5DzESPMevAJ4ICnhwreM5F4fGXgVNeagLCb3nnoHeg845cLkDY4gR9nQzGVhJVBExjY60UEAA)

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for writing such a treat of a response. I will analyze it carefully and try to understand everything.

Again, thank you.